# this.props undefined in React native: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a component that is a flatlist and to use probs to pass down some information to the component in the `_renderItem` function:

```
class ArticleList extends React.PureComponent {
  _renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <DummyText title={item.title} />
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={articles}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ArticleList;
```

This is the component for the FlatList.

The DummyText Component is very simple and just for trial purposes:

```
class DummyText extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default DummyText;
```

However, when I do this, the `this.probs` part appears to be undefined and I get an error saying:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

I have made sure that the item has an attribute title and it works fine if the `_renderItem`directly creates `<View><Text>{item.title}</Text></View>`.

Comment: Are you sure that your item has a title? Try changing `<DummyText title={item.title} />` to `<DummyText title="hello" />` to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Fix typo.

`this.probs.title`

=>

`this.props.title`

## Why

Normally, `undefined` message say there is no value. Thus, you able to know easily what is wrong from `title`'s parent value. And typo is happened often including me and it will be prevent by using linter as [ESLint](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwinu5nY7YrgAhUHF4gKHWxXBxQQFjABegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Feslint.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw3BGEnWIUCsLA7AsBnz99Wm).

Comment: Man, thank you, I feel embarrassed but nevertheless really appreciate the help because I have not been able to fix this for some time. Thanks!

Comment: @Cactus I make same mistake sometimes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are not passing `item` to your `_renderItem` function

```
render() {
   return (
     <View>
        <FlatList
           data={articles}
           renderItem={this._renderItem}
           keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
     </View>
   );
}
```

You have to pass `item` to your `_renderItem` function as,

```
render() {
   return (
     <View>
        <FlatList
           data={articles}
           renderItem={(item) => this._renderItem(item)}
           keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
     </View>
   );
}
```

Then same as you are using,

```
_renderItem = ({ item }) => (
   <DummyText title={item.title} />
);
```